# Rails: how to test before_save callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, private-members

Given a typical ActiveRecord model, I often have `before_save` callbacks that parse input, for instance taking something like `time_string` from the user and parsing it into a `time` field.

That setup might look like this:

```
before_save :parse_time
attr_writer :time_string

private
def parse_time
  time = Chronic.parse(time_string) if time_string
end
```

I understand that it's considered best practice to make callback methods private. However, if they're private, then you can't call them individually to test them in isolation.

So, for you seasoned Rails testers out there, how do you handle testing this kind of thing?

Comment: Where do you use that `time` variable? is that an attribute of your object?

Comment: The example above is kind of fabricated, but yes, the time variable is an object attribute.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Ruby, Private methods are still available via `Object#send`

You can exploit this for your unit testing like so:

```
project = Project.new
project.time_string = '2012/11/19 at Noon'
assert_equal(project.send(:parse_time), '2012-11-19 12:00:00')
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize `#send` worked that way. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

What I would do is save the state of an `new` or `build` instance of your object, save the object and make the assertion or expectation based on the value of the attribute that was changed by `before_save`

```
post = Post.new
post.time_string = '2012/11/19'
expected_time = Chronic.parse(post.time_string)
post.save
assert_equal(post.time, expected_time)
```

That way you are testing the behavior of how the object should act and not necessarily the implementation of the method.

Comment: Ok, but there are two major downsides to this: (1) it's slow. (2) `#save` runs all the callbacks, and if another callback errors out than the test for this would fail also, even though it might be working.

Comment: I like this way also, since it shouldn't matter how the internals work, as long as the end state is correct, but there are advantages (speed, coverage, understanding) to testing the methods directly.

Comment: Re: testing behavior vs. implementation, I understand what you mean, but the goal here is to test the behavior of the method in isolation rather than an integration test covering multiple behaviors. Testing methods individually doesn't mean you're necessarily testing implementation instead of behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There are times when I have an `if` condition on my callbacks in which case I use `run_callbacks`.

```
before_save :parse_time, :if => Proc.new{ |post| post.foo == 'bar' }
```

is tested positively by

```
post = Post.new
post.foo = 'bar'
expected_time = Chronic.parse(post.time_string)
post.run_callbacks :before_save
assert_equal(post.time, expected_time)
```

and negatively by

```
post = Post.new
post.foo = 'wha?'
post.run_callbacks :before_save
assert_nil(post.time)
```

See [the API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Callbacks.html) and [a blog](http://jacopretorius.net/2013/10/testing-activerecord-callbacks.html) for more details.